# CSS: position absolute fails in resizing

Tags: css, position

So, I have this image with CSS styling:

```css
.city1 {
  position: absolute;
  /* float: left; */
  top: 34px;
  left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<a href="malmo/">
  <img class="city1" src="images/city.png" alt="Malmö">
</a>
```

Issue is when I use the `position: absolute;` and I resize my browser, it changes the position.

You may now say that's because it's a absolute position and it follows the browser when you resize and such, but how do I solve this so it doesn't move?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `float:left` _and_ `position:absolute;`?

Comment: oops forgot to take away that, i just tried if it should work..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Item with absolute position should be inside a block element with `position:relative`. For example you can try to put your `<a ..><img /></a>` in a `<div>` as such:

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
#cont a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <a href="malmo/">
    <img class="city1" src="images/city.png" alt="Malmö">
  </a>
</div>
```

Now it should stay at fixed position even if you resize your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed`. But be aware `fixed` has cross browser issues.

Comment: it still changes position when i resize, even with fixed.

Comment: I doubt it; if you have actually applied fixed, it will override everything else, and the coordinates specified (left/right, top/bottom) will peg at that position relative to the viewport. This will always work if the CSS rule is being applied.

Comment: +1, being relative to the viewport is different from being relative to the body, eg, you might not want the item to still be shown when you scroll down.