# CSS positioning is weird when reducing the viewport

Tags: css, position, resize

I run a site using a liquid tri-column layout with a header. The layout runs nicely for more than a decade with all browsers I ever dared to try. It is based on absolute positioning in CSS. [This page](http://www.tan-tra.de/buch-rezension/dinge-wie-sie-sind/) provides an example of the actual site.

Watching the page from my tablet I found that the right column overlaps the center matter. Further investigation using Firebug showed that once the center content reaches 360px width, the right margin of the div shrinks. Why is that? Since Firefox and Android render the same, I guess that this is something, which is actually supposed to be.

However, I tried to make virtue out of necessity and experimented setting min-width for body and content and made the body scroll overflow. The body actually scrolls, but the right column is positioned on the right edge of the viewport instead of the body element (Firefox). Is this intentional CSS standard?

Any ideas how to solve the presentation on small displays?

Thanks for your efforts,
 – lars.

Comment: One of the [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442943/css-position-absolute-fails-in-resizing) did the trick for the last two questions. That leaves me with, why is there a 360px limit ... and how to deal with IE ;)?

Comment: Okay, got it all worked out thanks to several related questions, which I whished had popped up beforehand, and some more diligent investigation of my own code. Sorry, I cannot answer my question for now.

Comment: If your answer is worth sharing, post it as an answer, and accept it (after 48 hours). Otherwise, flag your question for moderator attention, and request a Delete).

Comment: Started the party too early. The _casus delicti_, i.e. Android, improved somewhat but still overlaps. But this apparently is a quirk with Android.

Answer (score 0):

I pondered a while whether I should revoke the question or provide this self-answer. I decided for the self-answer since I wished some of the answers in *related* had been presented when I wrote the question.

First the 360px limit apparently is my own stupidity. There is a comment form, which refuses to shrink. It scrolled out of my view.

The issue of the wiered positioning had been solved by adding `position:relative;` to the body. The reason is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442943/css-position-absolute-fails-in-resizing).

The `overflow` setting I used during experimenting is not necessary, since the default behaviour scrolls already. But using any `overflow` directive wrecks IE8.

So thanks a lot, the pool of answers finally had it all.