# image positions not working

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I can't seem to get boxclosed1.png to stay in the same spot if i re-size the browser. does anyone have any ideas? i'm testing in chrome. I tried to follow what was posted at this link: [CSS: position absolute fails in resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442943/css-position-absolute-fails-in-resizing)

**EDIT**: 
so i tried taking out all the other items (grass etc) and then it seems to be positioned correctly. in this case, what do i need to change about my current setup in divs and styles to make this work together?

Code:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-strict.dtd">

<!-- START HTML -->
<html>

    <!-- START HEAD -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/27.css" />

    <!-- END HEAD -->
    </head>

    <!-- START BODY -->
    <body>

        <div id="cont">
 <a href="malmo/"><img class="animated bounceInDown" src="boxclosed1.png" alt="Malmö"></a>
        </div>

    <!-- END BODY -->
    </body>

<!-- END HTML -->
</html>
```

Comment: It usually helps in these situations if you can provide a jsfiddle or something similar (there are many sites like this) so can you provide what works and what doesn't as two separate fiddles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place `boxclosed1.png` with `position: absolute` inside a `<div>` relatively positioned, then the image will be still *absolutely positioned* in relation to its parent, which will move if the browser is resized ... so does the image.

Move the image out of any container (before the `</body>` closing tag) and give it a `position: fixed` AND set its position in relation to the `bottom` and `right` of the page like

```
.fixed { position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; }
```

Check (and resize) **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeXU/)**

BTW, I wouldn't set `width` or `height` neither position to the `html` tag in order to avoid unexpected cross-browser results (unless you know exactly what you are doing)